# Phpcs is not reported on PhpStorm interface

Tags: phpstorm, phpcs

I'm trying to configure PHP Code Sniffer on my project, and I would like to see the error/warnings directly on the editor - like any other error, warnings.

I installed the package in composer `squizlabs/php_codesniffer` and configured the remote interpreter (since I'm using Docker).

If I run `phpcs` script the report is correctly shown:

[image]

At this point, I configured PhpStorm enabling Quality Tools -> PHP_CodeSniffer Validation:

[image]

When the code gets analyzed **I don't see anything highlighted on the Editor, but appears a popup that shows an XML**:

[image]

How can I enable editor highlight, instead of an Event popup that shows this XML?

Comment: Please check if this works with "Coding standard" set to any of the bundled standards, like PSR12, and not your custom standard.

Comment: I'm having the same issue on PhpStorm 2021.3. It appears to be a bug with the IDE. I also tried one of the bundled standards such as PSR2, and the same thing happens.

Comment: Issue filed at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-64562

Comment: great! i'll check it and hope will be foxed :)

Answer (score 1):

This is due to a bug with PhpStorm when the CLI interpreter settings are set to "Connect to existing container". If you toggle this to "Always use a new container", everything seems to work properly.

[image]

You can use `docker container prune` to remove the orphaned containers when your debugging session is complete.

You can follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-64562 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-64239 to track the status of this issue being resolved with JetBrains.

Comment: Yes, I already noticed that using "start a new container" works. The problem is about spawn new container each time and avoid use prune. I hope this will be foxed by jetbrains soon